# How to delete the array of structures if the memory block was manually overwritten

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

I know that example provided below is a rather bad pattern to follow, but I would like to ask this question out of curiosity.

In this situation:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    struct MyStruct {
        virtual ~MyStruct() = default;
        int dummyField;
    };
    int numpack = 1000;
    int memoryBlockSize = numpack*sizeof(MyStruct);
    char* buf = new char[memoryBlockSize];
    memset(buf, 0, memoryBlockSize);
    {
        MyStruct packets[numpack];
        memcpy(&packets, buf, memoryBlockSize);
    }  // segmentation fault on scope exit
    MyStruct* packets = new MyStruct[numpack];
    memcpy(packets, buf, memoryBlockSize);
    delete[] packets;  // segmentation fault on delete attempt
    delete[] buf;

    return 0;
}
```

segmentation fault is expected, because upon `packets` destruction it is not possible to find the destructor in the `MyStruct's` virtual table (memory was overwritten with zeros). In such a case, is it possible to gracefully delete the memory block pointed by `packets`?

Maybe there is a possibility to provide the (pointer + block size) to the delete function?

Or maybe I can try to repair the block pointed by `packets` by copying a memory from another memory block allocated in the same way (but the pointers in the virtual table will point to a different places in the memory):

```
MyStruct* anotherPackets = new MyStruct[numpack];
memcpy(packets, anotherPackets, memoryBlockSize);
```

Comment: You're causing lots of undefined behavior, there's no standard way to fix it.

Comment: try `free(packets)`

Comment: I tried. This is the result: `"free(): invalid pointer"`

Comment: @Ptaq666: The advice from "user582..." is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on `MyStruct`. If it has a non trivial destructor, because for example it contains a non empty `std::string` object, you have lost because when you erase the object, you will create a memory leak with the string characters. Things could even be worse depending on subobjects.

But is all you need is that destructors can be successfully called when `packets` go out of scope, you can simply use a *placement new* to construct (new) objects inside the array:

```
{
    MyStruct packets[numpack];
    memcpy(&packets, buf, memoryBlockSize);
    for (int i=0; i<numpack; i++) {
        new(packets+i) MyStruct();  // re-creates an object
    }
}   // the new objects are being destructed here
```

But as the destructors have not been called on initial objects, anything can happen because of that (that's what Undefined Behaviour means...). So please **never do that in real code**.

Comment: The destructor is already non-trivial because it's `virtual`. The concept of "trivial destructors" is a fiction to pretend that C-compatible types do have a C++ destructor. Also, with `for (i=0;i!=numpack;++i) (packets+i)->~MyStruct` you call the destructor on the initial objects. That fixes the UB.